# What in the relationship between EC2 instances and website volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This is as much as of a business question as anything else.  I am trying to forecast my company's server costs (AWS EC2) into the future.  However, I am stumped when forecasting the server costs.  Is there some approximate relationship between website traffic volume and EC2 instances or directly with EC2 costs?

Any advice would be hugely appreciated, or if you could point me to another resource (and yes I asked AWS themselves!) that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are referring "website volume" to the amount of traffic received. If yes, then there is no relation between EC2 and the website volume.

A good place to start is to use the pricing calculators[[1]](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html)[[2]](https://www.ec2instances.info) and then try understanding the pricing option. There are 3 options. On-Demand, Reserved Instances, and Spot Instances.

Example:

Are you planning to run your instances 24/7? then a reserved instance with full upfront payment can give you 75% discount.

Pricing for m3.medium instance.

- OnDemand - $586.920000 annually
- Reserved(1Year Upfront) $350.400000 annually
- Reserved(3Year Upfront) $227.760000 annually